# How to navigate(to list view/recordpage) when Component(Aura/LWC) is invoked from vf page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I am invoking AuraComponent from vf page and displaying selected contacts.Now on click of cancel button in component I tried to use Navigation mix and force:navigatetoSobject to navigate to listview/recordpage,both are not working.Is there any way for navigation when component invoked  from vf page?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please make sure to include the relevant portions of your code, along with the specific issue you are struggling with and the complete text and location of any errors, in the body of your question. See [ask] for more about our expectations, and please [edit] your question to add information rather than posting comments.

Comment: You can create an aura:attribute pass it from the VF page that aura:attribute should hold the current page reference than on cancel use window.location to redirect to previous page reference it will be great if you put some code snippet

Comment: Thanks Avijit it is now navigating the qiven url,but  view is showing below the tabs with whole page again.Please see screenshot.

Comment: In my case I need to go back to the previuos url ,So I used window.history.back().It navigates correctly.But issue is there when we specify the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

sampleCmp.cmp

```
<aura:component >
  <aura:attribute type="string" name="pgReference" />
  <button onclick="{!c.Cancel}">Cancel</button>
</aura:component >
```

sampleCmp.js

```
function : Cancel(component,event,helper){
  var pgRef = component.get("v.pgReference");
  window.location = pgRef;
}
```

Aura Application

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:sampleCmp"/>
</aura:application>
```

VF page

```
<apex:page >
 <apex:includeLightning />
 <div style="width:30%;height:100px;" id="sampleContainer" />
  <script>
    $Lightning.use("c:LightningOutContainerApp", function() {
      $Lightning.createComponent("c:sampleCmp",
      { 
      pgReference : "/apex/yoururl", 
      },
      "sampleContainer",
      function(cmp) {
        console.log('Component created, do something cool here');
      });
    });
  </script>
</apex:page>
```